# Сохранить состояние подгруженной страницы после обновления

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Есть обычный сайт Django, к примеру в нём 3 страницы HTML: (`index`) главная и две второстепенные (`contacts`, `news`). Мы кликаем по меню, подгружается через AJAX допустим `contacts`, но при обновлении страницы всё скидывается на главную `Index`.
Как сохранить состояние подгруженной страницы после обновления?

В пример два сайта, один как у меня сейчас, а второй как нужно:

1. [Ссылка](http://www.jeanhelfenstein.com/)
2. [Ссылка](https://www.redbullradio.com/browse)

Код моего скрипта:

```
$('#ajax_content').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      synch: 'true',
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/contacts/',
      success: function(data){
          $('#content').html(data)
          var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/"
          var state = { 'page_id': 2 };
          history.pushState(state, '', url);

      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Заменить адрес в адресной строке через history.pushState?

Comment: пробовал, но всё равно при обновлении страницы скидывается, также если нажать кнопку назад в браузере меняется url но подгрузка стоит на месте, код что я приводил поправил с history.pushState